I created an event, but it is never executed. Why?
I need to call a stored procedure every 10 minutes and I am using a recurring event, the problem is that it is not executed or I don't know how I can see if there is an error
Procedure:
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `simertg`.`estados_parqueos`()
BEGIN
set @HORA:= DATE_FORMAT(NOW( ),"%H:%i:00");
set @FECHA:= DATE_FORMAT(NOW( ),"%Y-%m-%d");
set @ID:=0;
select @ID:= estacionamiento_id from Estacionamiento_parqueo where tiempo_salida_t=@HORA and fecha=@FECHA;
UPDATE Estacionamiento_usuario_estacionamiento set estado=0 where estacionamiento_id=@ID;
END

Event:
CREATE EVENT actualizar
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 MINUTE
STARTS '2024-07-17 00:00:00.000'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DISABLE ON SLAVE
DO CALL estados_parqueos()

When I try to see the status it comes out like this:
+-------------+---------+---------------------+ 
| EVENT_NAME  | STATUS  | LAST_EXECUTED       | 
+-------------+---------+---------------------+ 
| actualizar  | SLAVESIDE_DISABLED| 2024-07-17 11:15:55 | 
+-------------+---------+---------------------+



Ensure the event scheduler is enabled. Variable 'event_scheduler' is a GLOBAL variable and should be set with SET GLOBAL as follows:
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON ;

Verify,
 SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'event_scheduler';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| event_scheduler | ON    |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)


To verify if the event has been executed use information_schema.EVENTS
SELECT EVENT_NAME,
       STATUS,
       LAST_EXECUTED  
FROM information_schema.EVENTS  
WHERE EVENT_SCHEMA = database()  
AND EVENT_NAME = 'insert10min';

+-------------+---------+---------------------+
| EVENT_NAME  | STATUS  | LAST_EXECUTED       |
+-------------+---------+---------------------+
| insert10min | ENABLED | 2024-07-17 17:57:55 |
+-------------+---------+---------------------+


Below I have created a step-by-step working example
I have created the following table
CREATE TABLE `myTbl` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_inserted` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

Store Procedure
DELIMITER &&

CREATE PROCEDURE insertEvery10Min()
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO myTbl (date_inserted) VALUES (NOW());
END&&

DELIMITER ;

Event
CREATE EVENT insert10min
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 MINUTE
DO
CALL insertEvery10Min();

Verify event status
 show events \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                  Db: test
                Name: insert10min
             Definer: root@localhost
           Time zone: SYSTEM
                Type: RECURRING
          Execute at: NULL
      Interval value: 10
      Interval field: MINUTE
              Starts: 2024-07-17 17:47:55
                Ends: NULL
              Status: ENABLED
          Originator: 1
character_set_client: utf8mb3
collation_connection: utf8mb3_general_ci
  Database Collation: utf8mb4_general_ci

Verify if data has been inserted on the table
select * from myTbl;
+----+---------------------+
| id | date_inserted       |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2024-07-17 17:57:55 |


+-------------+---------+---------------------+
| EVENT_NAME  | STATUS  | LAST_EXECUTED       |
+-------------+---------+---------------------+
| actualizar     | SLAVESIDE_DISABLED| 2024-07-17 11:15:55 |
+-------------+---------+---------------------+

@JohnnyUrdin are you trying to execute the event in the slave? Note when you create the event on the master in the slave it is automatically disabled.

I've seen it in the past whereby you have master to master replication set up. And so when you create the event on the "main" master, it is also technically a slave and so gets marked as slaveside disabled. In this case you simply have to enable it with alter event_name enable;
